# Losing information when applying function

Tags: scala

This averages the values contained in the map "mapped"

```
  case class Point(label: String, points: List[Double])

  val mapped = Map(Point("A4", List(5.0, 8.0)) -> List(Point("A3", List(8.0, 4.0)), Point("A4", List(5.0, 8.0))))
                                                  //> mapped  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[general.Point,List[general.Point]] 
                                                  //| = Map(Point(A4,List(5.0, 8.0)) -> List(Point(A3,List(8.0, 4.0)), Point(A4,Li
                                                  //| st(5.0, 8.0))))
  val averaged = mapped.values.map(m => m.map(m2 => m2.points).transpose.map(xs => xs.sum / xs.size))
                                                  //> averaged  : Iterable[List[Double]] = List(List(6.5, 6.0))
```

Using transpose causes the label information to be lost. How the values be averaged while at same time preserving the label so something like this is produced :

```
List(List(6.5, 6.0) , List(A3,A4))
```

instead of  :

```
List(List(6.5, 6.0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but here is a solution:

```
mapped.values.map(p => (p.map(_.points).transpose.map(xs => xs.sum / xs.size),
                        p.map(_.label)))
```